# AWS-CLI throwing unexpected Python based 'Session' error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have been using AWS CLI on Ubuntu for a month. But today AWS CLI is throwing a python error, I haven't seen before:

```
sashank@sashank:~$ aws configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 48, in main
    return driver.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 173, in main
    parser = self._create_parser()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 154, in _create_parser
    command_table['help'] = self.create_help_command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 149, in create_help_command
    cli_data.get('help_usage', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/help.py", line 259, in __init__
    HelpCommand.__init__(self, session, session.provider,
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'provider'
```

I have tried purging AWS CLI and removing all package files and re-installing, but error persists. Plz help!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have upgraded your virtualenv/setuptools and now your utility is screwed up. It happened to me with a wrongly set Chef that upgraded those two packages and, after that, the utility stopped working.

Comment: Yes.... downgrading setuptools helped but will apt-get update be a problem like this then?

Comment: you might be better off putting awscli in a virtualenv, so that you can keep everything as insulated as possible